# are parabolic points in the Mandelbrot set algebraic numbers?

Tags: minimal-polynomials, complex-dynamics, algebraic-numbers

Define the iterated quadratic polynomial:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_c^0(z) &= 0 \\
f_c^{n+1}(z) &= f_c^n(z)^2+c
\end{aligned}
$$

The $c$ for which $f_c^n(0)$ remains bounded form the Mandelbrot set, which has hyperbolic components (cardioid- and disc-like regions) with a rich structure of periodic attractors.

Points $c$ on the boundary of a period $P$ component at the bond point with a period $Pp$ child component satisfy (for some $z$):

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_c^P(z) &= z \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f_c^P(z) &= e^{2 \pi i \frac{q}{p}} \\
\gcd(q,p) &= 1
\end{aligned}
$$

Are all algebraic numbers? (I have found some that are.)

Are any algebraic integers? (I have found some that are not.)

What can be said about their degrees (as algebraic numbers) in relation to the $P$ and $p$?

Does the minimal polynomial remain the same when changing (only) $q$ while finding $c$ on the boundary of the same component?

Do points on the boundaries of different components of the same period have different minimal polynomial, even if $p$ and $q$ are the same?

Comment: There are also points whose Julia set is a Siegel disk that are also on the boundary of the main cardioid.  These have an irrational rotation number for the landing ray. They are not algebraic numbers.  They are on the boundary of the m-set.  There are uncountable infinite number of them.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244344/classification-of-points-in-the-mandelbrot-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: previous answer was misleading, sorry.

Here's how you can do it: consider the function 
$$P_n(c)=\prod_{z=f_c^n(z)} \left( (f_c^n)'(z)-e^{2i\pi p/q} \right)$$
Then clearly a parameter $c$ satisfies your property iff $P_n(c)=0$.

Now it is not clear at first glance that $P_n$ is a polynomial (or even continuous), but it is. Let $A:=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the field of algebraic numbers. Observe that $f_c^n(z)-z$ can be seen as a polynomial in $z$ with coefficients in $A[c]$ (actually even in $\mathbb Z[c]$), and let $Q_1$ denote that polynomial. Then $P_n(c)$ is the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $Q_1$ and of the polynomial $Q_2(z):=(f_c^n)'(z)-e^{2i\pi p/q}$, also with coefficients in $A[c]$.

Therefore, by properties of the resultant, $P_n(c) \in A[c]$, so the zeroes of $P_n$ are algebraic numbers.

In fact, this should also prove that parameters with an $n$-cycle of multiplier 1 are algebraic integers.

Comment: it is not obvious to me that two polynomials in two unknowns, with algebraic number coefficients, must only have algebraic number solutions - can you expand? (a link to a text that explains would be fine, I only have very basic a.n.t. background)

Comment: @Claude see my edit

Comment: regarding your last paragraph, $c=0.25$ ($n=1$) and $c=-1.75$ ($n=3$) both have multiplier $1$, but they are not algebraic integers (they are rational and not integers).  I will check the rest later (need to read up about resultants, thanks for the link)

Comment: @Claude you're right, it's because $Q_2$ is not monic I think (leading coefficient is an integer but not 1)

Comment: So, my first sub-question is answered.  Do you think it's possible to answer the second sub-question by an argument "$Q_1$ monic and $Q_2$ not monic implies (somehow) that the parameters are *not* algebraic integers? Or do you think should I split this M.SE question into multiple pages?