# Are there known points on the boundary of the Mandelbrot set which iterate forever?

Tags: fractals, complex-dynamics, iterated-function-system

Where $f(z)=z^2+c$ is the Mandelbrot iteration function, are there any known complex numbers $z$ such that iterating $z\to f(z)$ to infinity retains $z$ on the boundary (i.e. it does not explode to infinity or collapse to zero)?

If such known points exist, are they periodic?

Can we prove that they do or don't exist, without knowing their values?

Comment: The Mandelbrot set is defined by unbounded vs bounded, not by $\to \infty$ vs $\to 0$.
See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244344/classification-of-points-in-the-mandelbrot-set

Comment: Suggestion: try iterating some specific points by hand or with a computer, starting from $z=0$: for example, $c = -2, \frac{1}{4}, -\frac{3}{4}, -\frac{5}{4}, 0, -1, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{7}{8}$

Comment: You want to "retain $z$ on the boundary" of what? The Mandelbrot set does not live in the dynamical $z$-plane; it lives in the parameter $c$-plane. If you let $c$ be *any* complex number and then choose $z_0$ on the boundary of the corresponding Julia set, then the iterates of $z_0$ will remain on that boundary. In fact, there are some choices of $z_0$ where iterates will be dense in the Julia set.

Answer (score 0):

[Misiurewicz points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misiurewicz_point) lay on the boundary of the mandelbrot set and become periodic after some $n$ iterations. Branches of the set are proved to be these points, but their exact values are unknown, only approximated.