# Points $p$ in the Mandelbrot set such that $M\setminus\{p\}$ is not connected

Tags: complex-dynamics

Obviously, only the points in the boundary $p\in\partial M$ are interesting. I managed to prove a few examples:

For $p=\frac 14$ the set remains connected, since $M\cap \mathbb R=[-2,\frac 14]$ and the Mandelbrot contains the main cardioid.

For $p=-\frac 34$ the set loses connectivity since for a $c=-\frac 34+\epsilon i$ the fixed point which is parabolic at $\epsilon=0$ is $z_0=\frac 12-\sqrt{1-\epsilon i}$ and we have $|f'(z_0)|=1+\frac{\epsilon^2}4+O(\epsilon^4)$ so it is repelling for small $\epsilon$.

For $p=-2$, consider a parameter $|c|=2$, and we have $f^2(0)=c^2+c$ so $|f^2(0)|=2|c-1|$ which is only $\leq 2$ when $c=-2$ which means $M\setminus\{-2\}$ is contained in the open disk $B_2(0)$. Using a rather contrived argument I was able to prove that when $c\to -2$ with argument bounded by a certain positive function, the periodic point near $-1$ is attracting and attracts the origin so $c\in M$. Thus $M\setminus\{-2\}$ is connected.

Is there any relationship between this property and the other properties of points on the boundary of the MAndelbrot set? For example whether they are parabolic or not?

Comment: Note that both of your examples $p=1/4$ and $p=-3/4$ are both parabolic; thus, parabolic vs not parabolic is not an issue. (I assume the $p=3/4$ that you wrote is a typo.) I'm fairly certain that the landing points of the rational external rays (as [described here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9711213)) are exactly the articulation points you seek.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I agree that it makes sense that the landing point of an external ray has the property in the question, but I don't see why one would expect these to be the only points with the property.

Comment: @Derivative the point is that at least two rays should land at the same point, not just one

Comment: I think the keyword for two or more rays landing at the same point is **biaccessible**

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244344/classification-of-points-in-the-mandelbrot-set?rq=1